# Detect direction of rotating wheel iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a wheel on the screen and its rotatable. When the user swipe on the wheel it should start rotate based on swipe direction. I finished all functionality except the direction of rotation (either clockwise or anti clockwise). Any one can help me to find which direction the user swipe on the wheel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_direction = 1;
if(_startPoint.y < rotarCenter.y) {

    if(_startPoint.x > endTouchPoint.x)
        _direction = -1;
}
else if(_startPoint.y > rotarCenter.y) {

    if(_startPoint.x < endTouchPoint.x)
        _direction = -1;
}

if(_startPoint.x < rotarCenter.x && endTouchPoint.x < rotarCenter.x) {

    if(_startPoint.y < endTouchPoint.y)
        _direction = -1;
    else
        _direction = 1;
}
else if(_startPoint.x > rotarCenter.x && endTouchPoint.x > rotarCenter.x) {

    if(_startPoint.y > endTouchPoint.y)
        _direction = -1;
    else
        _direction = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rotation is

**Solution 1:**

**clockwise**

- if touch point.y is above wheel center and swipe is from small touch point.x to greater x. or
- if point.y is below wheel center and swipe is from greater point.x to smaller x.

**counter clockwise:**
 the oppsite:

- if point.y is below wheel center and swipe is from small touch point.x to greater x. or
- if point.y is above wheel center and swipe is from greater point.x to smaller x.

There are better solutions, with more complex mathematics, but the one is a simple one.

**Update** This one is simple, too and better!

**Solution 2:**

Caculate the angle between wheel center ( x,y) to touch (x,y):

```
 double angleRad =   atan2(dy/dx), where dy = touch.y - wheel.y, and dx analog.
```

Do that for each touch event: if the angle is increasing, then its clockwise, else counter clockwise

Comment: Keep in mind that if you attempt to animate the wheel you must do it in increments, since any rotation of more than 180 degrees takes the shortest path (ie, backwards).

Comment: @AlexWien Thank you very much for your help AlexWien. Its really helped me out. I added few more conditions for the changes in the y coordinate also as given in the code below